Symfony Security access_control and jwt auth issue
Issue:
I'm encountering difficulties with security configuration in my Symfony application. Specifically, I'm having issues accessing routes protected by access_control.
Context:
I'm using Symfony to develop a web application with authentication features.
I've configured a main firewall with multiple zones, including a stateless API zone.
Tokens are generated by lexikJWTAuthenticationBundle on the Symfony side, not by React.
Requests to routes protected by access_control fail with a 401 error, while requests with Postman work correctly with the same JWT token.
What I've Tried:
Checked the security configuration in security.yaml, especially the access_control rules.
Compared the HTTP requests sent by the React application with those sent by Postman to detect any differences.
Verified CORS configurations with Nelmio CORS Bundle to ensure requests are allowed from the React application.
Tried different approaches to secure access to routes, including using $this->getUser() in controllers.
Debugged requests and HTTP responses using browser development tools to identify any errors.
Checked Symfony logs for any security or authentication-related errors or warnings.
Setted .env as below :
CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN=http://localhost:3000

JWT_SECRET_KEY=%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/private.pem
JWT_PUBLIC_KEY=%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/public.pem
JWT_PASSPHRASE=mypassword

Sample Security Configuration:
 firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        lazy: true
        provider: app_user_provider
        remember_me:
            secret: '%kernel.secret%'
            always_remember_me: true

        logout:
            path: logout

        json_login:
            check_path: api_login
            username_path: email
            password_path: password
            success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

    api:
        pattern: ^/api
        stateless: true
        jwt: ~

Sample Axios Request from React Application:
const response = await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_URL_API}/api/truc`, {
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userToken}`,
    },
});

Questions:
What could be causing the failure of requests with Axios from the React application, while requests with Postman work?
How can I resolve the issue of accessing routes protected by access_control in Symfony?
